# orWhere not working with Laravel eloquent relationship query

Tags: php, database, laravel-4, eloquent

In Laravel, I have two tables named Booking and Clients. For a specific booking, I have belongsTo relation with a single Client. Everything works well when I query a client for a booking except when I include orWhere. Please look at the code snippet below.

```
if($client_name!=null)
        {
            $client_name='%'.$client_name;
            $bookings=$bookings->whereHas('client',function($q) use ($client_name){
                $q->where('first_name','LIKE',$client_name)
                    //->orWhere('last_name','LIKE',$client_name);                 
            });
        }
```

With the commented out orWhere line, I get proper bookings with the client with `first_name` as specified by user. But when I use or in the query for `last_name`, all the rows are displayed as if `last_name` matched for every row.

What's wrong with it? Help please.

Comment: Check the query that is run with `DB::getQueryLog()` for example

Comment: Following is the last output: select * from `throttle` where `user_id` = ? limit 1. I am using Sentry package for authentication. Query above is run in admin page.

Comment: This doesn't tell us anything, check the one for `clients` table. Simply run the code you pasted and straight away `dd(DB::getQueryLog())` or simply  do it in CLI with artisan tinker

Comment: Running dd(DB::getQueryLog()) just after the code above gives the output: array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(44) "select * from `users` where `id` = ? limit 1" ["bindings"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(1) } ["time"]=> float(1) } [1]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(52) "select * from `throttle` where `user_id` = ? limit 1" ["bindings"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(1) } ["time"]=> float(1) } }. Don't know why it doesn't show query related to Booking table.

Comment: Oh well.. Because you didn't run the query! Append `get()` or `first()` at the end, so `$bookings` will hold the query result instead of the query builder.

Comment: @deczo, you caught it! Now I get the query: select * from `limo_booking` where `limo_booking`.`deleted_at` is null and `is_cancelled` = ? and (select count(*) from `limo_clients` where `limo_booking`.`client_id` = `limo_clients`.`id` and `first_name` like ? or `last_name` like ?) >= ? order by `id` desc . Could you notice any problem with it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that you have such code now:

```
WHERE foreignKey = X AND first_name = Y OR last_name = Z
```

So obviously it's not returning what it should.

Now, to make it work, you need to add those constraints as a sub where:

```
$bookings=$bookings->whereHas('client',function($q) use ($client_name){
            $q->where( function ($q) use ($client_name) {
                $q->where('first_name','LIKE',$client_name)
                    ->orWhere('last_name','LIKE',$client_name);
            });
        });
```

This will result in a query like:

```
WHERE foreignKey = X AND (first_name = Y OR last_name = Z)
```

which is what you need.